# Rod and disk pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

This is the problem from book Introduction to Mechanics by Kleppner D kolenkow 7.18

Find the period of a pendulum consisting of a disk of mass M and radius R fixed to the end of a rod of length l and mass m. How does the period change if the disk is mounted to the rod by a frictionless bearing so that it is perfectly free to spin?

I am unable to figure it out why disk will not rotate when it  is mounted to frictionless bearing ? Please help me!

Comment: If you need a worked out solution, you can take a look at this:
https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/anchordoqui/chapter24.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If the disc rotates free, its angular frequency is constant independent of the dynamics of the rod with a point mass of the disk in the axis of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

To make the disc rotate about its centre of mass requires a torque about the centre of mass to be applied to the disc and that torque is not present if the bearing is frictionless.